# Windows/Drillbit Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit

Tags: windows, hadoop, cluster-computing, apache-zookeeper, apache-drill

I have set up a Hadoop single node cluster with pseudo distributed operations, and YARN running. I am able to use `Spark JAVA API` to run queries as a YARN-client. I wanted to go one step further and try Apache Drill on this `"cluster"`. I installed Zookeeper that is running smoothly but I am not able to start drill and I get this log:

nohup: ignoring input

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit

Any idea?

I am on `Windows 10` with `JDK 1.8`.

Comment: What version of Drill you are using? How you try to start Drill? Do you want to run Drill under YARN? 
https://drill.apache.org/docs/launch-drill-under-yarn/

Comment: I am using Drill 1.14.  I start drill with the following command: drillbit.sh start

I tried to follow the explanations for drill under YARN but I got a similar error when I run the command "drill-on-yarn.sh --site C:/BigData/drill/site start".
> Could not find or load main class org.apache.drill.yarn.client.DrillOnYarn

I suspect that there is a problem with my drill-install path. Here is how I setup the path in my drill-on-yarn.conf file:
`drill.yarn: {
  ...
  drill-install:  {
 client-path: "C:\BigData\drill\apache-drill-1.14.0.tar.gz"
  }
  ....
`

Answer (score 0):

DRILL CLASSPATH is not initialized in the process of running drillbit on your machine. 

For the purpose to start Drill on Windows machine it is necessary to run sqlline.bat script, for example:

```
C:\bin\sqlline sqlline.bat –u "jdbc:drill:zk=local;schema=dfs"
```

See more info: https://drill.apache.org/docs/starting-drill-on-windows/

Comment: Thank you! However, I do not understand how to run it on yarn that runs on my Hadoop single node cluster that I run locally. Do I miss anything? Isn't it possible?

Comment: You can run Drill on Windows easily. But I'm not sure that Drill on Yarn under Windows OS setup was was checked by someone. At first try to run Drill in embedded mode and than to do it under Yarn.

Comment: Also to avoid obtaining "Drillbit class not found Exception", please try to setup DRILL_HOME for your Drill distribution:
https://github.com/apache/drill/blob/master/distribution/src/resources/drill-config.sh#L27
https://github.com/apache/drill/blob/master/distribution/src/resources/drill-config.sh#L156